# How to fix window size eclipse RCP?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I want to set fixed size of window created through eclipse RCP.
How it can be achieved?

```java
parent.getShell();
body = form.getBody();
body.setBounds(500, 500, 350, 200);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may set size of your application window in `preWindowOpen()` method of `ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor` class

```java
public void preWindowOpen() {
    IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer configurer = getWindowConfigurer();
    configurer.setInitialSize(new Point(500, 350));
}
```

Comment: It's just initial size. It will be stretchable after that